# iOS |3D Touch | ContextMenu Configuration Custom Preview | Background Color

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu

I am trying to implement Content Menu for ios 13 for peek.
This is I have implemented for Menu configuration

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

       return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: identifier, previewProvider: {
        let preview = TitlePreviewViewController_v2.create(with: title, moduleId: 
        self.viewModel?.getMouleId())
        preview.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        return preview
    }, actionProvider: { suggestedActions in
        
        // Create an action for sharing
        let share = UIAction(title: "Share", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")) { action in
            print("Sharing Me")
        }

        // Create other actions...

        return UIMenu(title: "", children: [share])
    })
}
```

what I want is to set the background color of previwe
as transparent. But I am unable to do so. Check the screenshot. The white background
I want to change it to transparent.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you show code of `TitlePreviewViewController_v2`?

Comment: Just take it as a view controller with background = .clear